# Display Time Difference between 2 dates

Tags: vb.net

I want to display a date and time difference between 2 dates. And I am stuck with this code :(

Take a look at this code:

```
Dim d1 As DateTime = "2/13/2018 1:50:00 PM"
Dim d2 As DateTime = "2/20/2018 1:50:00 PM"

   Dim count = Enumerable.Range(0, (d2 - d1).TotalHours).
               Select(Function(i) d1.AddHours(i).DayOfWeek).
               Where(Function(d) d <> DayOfWeek.Sunday And d <> DayOfWeek.Saturday).
              Count()

   MessageBox.Show("Time Consumed: " & count)
```

My desired output should be like this. `40:00:00`
excluding the sundays and saturdays and for every week days the timespan is only for 8:00 AM - 5:00PM

Comment: What are you stuck with? What doesn't work with this code?

Comment: With this code I am stuck with the output that only shows the number of Hours of the two dates

Comment: also I cant find or I dont have an idea how to work around the filtering the time of weekdays for 8:00 - 5:00 only

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to calculate? Please be specific, i.e. "Given two `DateTime` values I want the count of ___".

Comment: Please take a look with the code above. with the two dates above I want to calculate the total Hours and minutes excluding the sundays and saturdays, also to filter the time for every weekdays which is 8:00 - 5:00 only

Comment: The timespan 8 am to 5pm is 9 hours, why do you expect the result to be 40? Are you deducting a break or am i missing something?

Comment: actually you're right, I am deducting a break

Comment: @CallMeJeo - Please describe what you want to do *without referring to your code* and be **very** specific. The phrase "I want to calculate the total Hours and minutes excluding the sundays and saturdays, also to filter the time for every weekdays which is 8:00 - 5:00 only" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @CallMeJeo At what time is the break? If d1 had a time of 11:50 AM, would there still be a break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I liked Enigmativity's answer a lot, so I thought I'd expand on it:

```
Dim minutes =
    Enumerable _
        .Range(0, CInt(d2.Subtract(d1).TotalMinutes)) _
        .Select(Function(m) d1.AddMinutes(m)) _
        .Where(Function(d) d.Hour >= 8 And d.Hour < 17) _
        .GroupBy(Function(d) d.DayOfWeek) _
        .Where(Function(g) g.Key <> DayOfWeek.Saturday And g.Key <> DayOfWeek.Sunday) _
        .Select(Function(g) g.Count()) _
        .Sum()

MessageBox.Show("Time Consumed: " & Math.Floor(minutes / 60) & " hours " & minutes Mod 60 & " mins")
```

Comment: Shoot! This made my day! :D I am super satisfied with the result. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Does this do it?

```
Dim d1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2/13/2018 1:50:00 PM")
Dim d2 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2/20/2018 1:50:00 PM")

Dim count = _
    Enumerable _
        .Range(0, Cint(d2.Subtract(d1).TotalHours)) _
        .Select(Function(i) d1.AddHours(i).DayOfWeek) _
        .Where(Function(d) d <> DayOfWeek.Sunday And d <> DayOfWeek.Saturday) _
        .Distinct() _
        .Count() * 8
```

NB: Please turn `Option Strict On` for your code - it'll help you be a better coder.

Comment: Ughh thanks this works. But how is it works sir?? and Is it possible to display also the minutes?? i.e 40:00

Comment: This only works on full days, so if d1 and d2 had different hour it wouldnt give correct result

Comment: Ohh I see, Thanks for the response

Comment: I tried to change one of the date, why is it the result didn't change??

Comment: @Zulatin - That doesn't seem to be a requirement from the OP.